SMS not working between Android Emulators
I'm developing an Android app that sends SMS messages. While the app works correctly on physical devices, I'm unable to send or receive SMS messages between Android emulators. This issue persists even when using the built-in SMS app on the emulators.
Android Studio 2022.3.1
Emulators:
Pixel 2 with Android 13 (API level 33, codename: VanillaIceCream)
Pixel 7 Pro with Android 13 (API level 33, codename: VanillaIceCream)
private void sendSMS() {
    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String message = messageEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!phoneNumber.isEmpty() && !message.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(this, "SMS sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to send SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter phone number and message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

What I have tried:
Using the correct emulator phone numbers: sending from 5554 to 5556
Testing the app on physical devices (works correctly)
Sending SMS directly from the emulator's built-in SMS app (doesn't work)

An old post related to your question here.
You can probably follow this answer.

That solution no longer works. It might have been effective in 2011, but is sending an SMS from one emulator to another possible in newer versions of Android Studio?. While sending an SMS via telnet did work, that's not the method I'm looking for.

I get the feeling that they stopped maintaining the emulators' SMS functionality years ago, and it's simply luck that any of it still works. If you don't necessarily need two separate emulator instances for your tests, an emulator can still send to itself, all the way up to V (35), at least. I updated a post about something similar just the other day, and tested several different versions by having the emulator send to its own port.
